# Ms-Office 2007 custom installation script

Tags: installation, microsoft-office, script

I'd like to make a script for Ms-office 2007 custom installation easily and to put some restriction for users. 
when the user run that script  the script only install the flowing packages:-  word, excel, access & powerpoint.

How can i do that? any idea?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running the Volume License version, you can run setup.exe /admin to run the the Office Customization Tool (OCT). It can configure almost every option in Office.

Check out the following links:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179207(office.12).aspx (deployment document)

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=7240 (videos)

Here is a screenshot, which looks a lot like a Group Policy MMC:

[image]

I looked, and it seems to be a lot more complicated with non-VL versions, and will require you to directly edit an XML file. This is the best document explaining how to do this I could find:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/office_resource_kit/archive/2008/11/05/how-to-create-and-deploy-custom-2007-office-configurations.aspx

It is simple with the OCT if you have it, not so simple, if you don't.